# Older version of firefox developer redistributable

Tags: firefox-developer-edition

Does anyone knows where mozilla hides its listing of older versions of firefox developer redistributable ?

I cannot find anything on archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

(or maybe it's behind a codename. Still need help anyhow)

The firefox team is refusing to give this information at all cost

Comment: What does "redistributable" mean in this context?

Comment: If you attempt to download firefox through the main page you will always get a "small installer" that downloads the actual firefox. The actual firefox is the redistributable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Mozillas ftp for the dev edition download installers.
[Index of /pub/devedition/releases/](https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/devedition/releases/)

Comment: Unfortunately, at this point (may have been different before) that page only has ftp/download for Developer Editions back to version 54 (  54.0b11 --- 62.0b9). Is there a file archive that has earlier versions?